# D3 event not working in Chrome, but working in JSfiddle in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Ripping my hair out trying to figure out this inconsistent behavior. Fiddle below
When I load this page using a local http server (node, or python) in Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 the mouseover event fires on a mouseclick inside and outside of the object, but it works correctly in JSfiddle and IE11.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/30gtwqt0/2/).

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
            //debugger
            console.log("test")
            d3.select(this)
              .style("stroke-width", "10px")
              .style("opacity", 1);
          })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            //debugger
            console.log("test2")
            d3.select(this)
              .style("stroke-width", null)
              .style("opacity", null);
          });
```

Comment: So, your fiddle seems to give a blank output

Comment: I fixed your fiddle link, but I'm confused by the question.  You are saying the fiddle works with chrome and IE but when you load the very same html/JavaScript through your local server the events don't fire?  Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: Yes, works in IE and and JSFiddle in Chrome, but not in Chrome with local web server. What's weird is if I click on the line the event callback fires. I'll see if I can upload a GIF or a video showing the issue later today. Thanks Mark

Comment: I'm completed baffled but this solved itself after I loaded in a different set of data. I really appreciate the suggestions and help.